# Embedded Vimeo Timestamp Link Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, vimeo-player

I used to be able to get this to work where I press the link of the song, and it will jump to the time of the embedded Vimeo video in my site(Wordpress). The codes are as below:

HTML

```
<div class="wpb_video_widget wpb_content_element vc_clearfix   vc_video-aspect-ratio-169 vc_video-el-width-100 vc_video-align-center">
<iframe id="player_1" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/xxxxxxx?dnt=1&app_id=122963?api=1&player_id=player_1" width="1080" height="720" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
<div class="links">
<a class="link_1" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">Track 1 “Song Name”</a><br/>
<a class="link_2" href="javascript:void(0);" target="_self">Track 2 "Name of song"</a><br/>
```

JS Script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

// Set lesson times (in seconds)
var link_1_track = 000; 
var link_2_track = 323; 

// Function to hide all status messages
hidePlayNoticeAll = function() {
    jQuery(".link_1_status").html("");
    jQuery(".link_2_status").html("");

// Load Vimeo API for the embedded video
var iframe_player = jQuery('#player_1')[0];
var player_1 = $f(iframe_player);

// Function to control what happens when each lesson link is clicked
function setupLinks() {
        
    jQuery(".link_1").click(function () {
        player_1.api('play'); //Play the video
        player_1.api('seekTo', link_1_track); //Seek to the number of seconds in the variable link_1_track
        hidePlayNoticeAll(); // Hide all status messages before displaying (to prevent them from sticking) 
        jQuery(".link_1_status").html(playNotice); //Display status message (playNotice) within span with class link_1_status
    });
    
    jQuery(".link_2").click(function () {
        player_1.api('play');
        player_1.api('seekTo', link_2_track);
        hidePlayNoticeAll();
        jQuery(".link_2_status").html(playNotice);
    });
}

setupLinks();


</script>
```

Is there anything wrong with the code? Or do I need an API from vimeo or jquery? I cant remember what I did to make it work before. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the API that I needed to get this working. So I will be closing my own question haha.

The script made it worked like a charm, in case anyone wants to use the code, this is the script below. Cheers.

```
<script src="https://f.vimeocdn.com/js/froogaloop2.min.js"></script>
```